# How to get the POST/GET params in a java WebMethod?

Tags: java, web-services, http

I have created a java web service with netbeans 7.1 (glassfish3.1).

It is supposed to be visited via clicking a URL (like: http://localhost:8080/ImageService/GetImage?visitDate='2012-01-01') to generate an image for web users. And there are some parameters in the URL that I need to get to use inside the `WebMethod`.

```
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetImage")
    public void GetImage() {
      // Date visitDate = GET["visitDate"];
      ...
    }
```

Or, how can I make the java web service invoked via http get method?

PS: In .net, this config will enable the feature - calling a web service via URL. I'm asking  for a java version.

```
<webServices>
 <protocols>
  <add name="HttpPost"/>
  <add name="HttpGet"/>
 </protocols>
</webServices>
```

Is this doable? How can I get that work?

Thanks!

Finally, I have given up this, turn to use jsp to do that. But still hoping someone can tell me - if web-service way is possible or not.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `request.getParameter("visitDate");`

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work in a web service method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @WebParam annotation is defined by the javax.jws.WebParam interface. It is placed on the parameters of the methods defined in the SEI. The @WebParam annotation allows you to specify the direction of the parameter, if the parameter will be placed in the SOAP header, and other properties of the generated wsdl:part.

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "GetImage")
public void GetImage(@WebParam(name = "visitDate")String visitDate) {

  //...
}
```

Comment: But I just want to get the param from the URL, is it possible?

Comment: So that won't be a JAX-RPC, will it?

Comment: No, it won't. The users will just click a url, passing dynamic params like this: localhost:8080/ImageService/GetImage?visitDate='2012-01-01'